# Query a Embedded document inside a array

Tags: mongodb

**Schema:**

```
{
    "Name" : "Ammulu",
    "Details" : [ 
        {
            "Date" : "2018-08-10",
            "Client" : "Mongo",
            "ChargeCode" : {
                "Test" : "2",
                "Analysis" : "1",
                "Meeting" : "3"
            }
        },
    {
            "Date" : "2018-08-11",
            "Client" : "Mongo",
            "ChargeCode" : {
                "Test" : "2",
                " Cod " : "1",
                "Meeting" : "3"
            }
        },
    {
            "Date" : "2018-08-12",
            "Client" : "Mongo",
            "ChargeCode" : {
                "Test" : "2",
                " Cod " : "1",
                "Meeting" : "3"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to export this schema into `csv` file, i tried this query :

```
mongoexport --db sample --collection test --fields Name,Details.0.Date --query "{'Name':/Ammulu/)}" --type=csv --out C:\Users\home\Desktop\users.csv
```

I get this output:

```
Name      Details.0.Date

Ammulu     2018-08-10
```

I want to export the schema in this format and also retrieve all dates in the details array

```
Name     Date            ChargeCode 

Ammulu   2018-08-10 Test : 2,  Analysis : 1, Meeting : 3

         2018-08-11 Test : 2,  Cod : 1, Meeting : 3

         2018-08-12 Test : 2,  Cod : 1, Meeting : 3
```

any help thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the aggregation framework to filter your documents using the above query as your [$match](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) operator and then write the documents returned by the aggregation pipeline to a specified collection using the [$out](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/) operator.

```
db.col.aggregate([
       { "$match": { "Name": "Ammulu" } },
       { "$unwind": "$Details" },
       { "$project": { "Name": 1, "Date": "$Details.Date", "ChargeCode": 
                       "$Details.ChargeCode", "_id": 0 } },
       { "$out": "out_data" }
])
```

Here export to CSV [mongoexport](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongoexport/)

```
mongoexport --db db_name --collection out_data --fields Name,Date,ChargeCode --type csv --out out_path
```

Comment: Thanks for your response